# SkaMPI compilation error, Makefile.dep:5: *** missing separator.

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, gnu-make

I was trying to compile SkaMPI 5 using latest GNU make(3.81), but getting below error :

```
        make -f Makefile.dep MPICC="mpicc" CFLAGS="-O2" skampi
        make[1]: Entering directory          
        Makefile.dep:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.
        make[1]: Leaving directory 
        make: *** [skampi] Error 2
```

Comment: Why are you using `-f Makefile.dep`? Did the usual build process fail in some way?

Comment: Thats the error, I have simply executed make command with no arguments.